# How to match objectids inside arrays using the mongo functions?

Tags: arrays, match

Can we match the objectids in two arrays , combine the data  using mongo aggregation or do we need to use promises

```
Collection2
{
DId: ObjectId("5e3407a40a5c8123cfb0deb7"),
DInfo : [{"SectionEdited": true,
"SectionID": ObjectId("5e314c5021c3f94eea31c7c2")},
{"SectionComments": "BBBB","SectionEdited": false,"SectionID": ObjectId("5e314c5021c3f94eea31c7c1")}]
}
Collection 1
{DId: ObjectId("5e3407a40a5c8123cfb0deb7"),DDetails : [{SDetails: {SN: Section1,SSD: [{_id = ObjectId("5e314c5021c3f94eea31c7c1"),SectionQues: "Ques1"
}]}}]}
```

Result Required
{DId: ObjectId("5e3407a40a5c8123cfb0deb7")
DD : [{SD: {SN: Section1,SSD: [{_id = ObjectId("5e314c5021c3f94eea31c7c1"),SQ: "Ques1","SC": "BBBB","SE": false
}]}}]}

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for join using ids of two column then it can be done by `$lookup`

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents()>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

You can use objectid field of first table in `localField` & objectid field of next table in `foreignField`.

You can look for details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: If you can provide example of what you have & what you need then it'll help understand requirement better

Comment: It is a multilevel nested array so I was not able to get it working using lookup